# If $t = \tanh (x/2)$, prove what $\sinh (x)$ and $\cosh (x)$ are in terms of $t$?

Tags: calculus

If $t = \tanh (x/2)$

Prove $\sinh (x) = \frac{2t}{ 1 - t^2 }$ and $\cosh (x) = \frac{ 1 + t^2 }{  1 - t^2 }$

Comment: From a previous question I have tan ( x + y ) = (tanh x + tanh y) / (1 + tanh x tanh y)  t = tanh (x/2)  using the result from the previous question I have 2t / (1 + t^2) = tanh(x) = sinh(x)/cosh(x) I'm struggling to get sinh(x) and cosh(x) on their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$tanh(\frac{x}{2})=t=\frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{-x}{2}}} *\frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}\\=\\t=\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\\e^x(t-1)=-t-1\\e^x=\frac{t+1}{1-t}\\$$now put e^x in sinh , cos h
$$sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\\\frac{\frac{t+1}{1-t}-\frac{1-t}{1+t}}{2}\\=\frac{2t}{1-t^2} $$and like this for coshx

Comment: Thank you! I have got it now

Answer (score 0):

use that $\tanh(x/2)=\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)+1}=\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{\sinh(x)}$
and
$\cosh(x)^2-\sinh(x)^2=1$